# How can I code some function that executes if my $http has a success or error?

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple $http call:

```
    $http({
        url: '/api/abc/Post',
        method: "POST",
        data: home.modal.data
    })
    .success(function (result) {

    })
    .error(function(error) {

    });
```

How can I code some function that will execute at the end after either the .success or the .error has returned ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$http` returns a promise. On recent Angular versions, the `finally` method of the promise does what you want, with the catch that, since it is a reserved word for Javascript, you will have to call it as:

```
$http({...})
    .success(function (result) {...})
    .error(function(error) {...})
    ['finally'](function() {...});
```

Comment: This can be found under https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#the-promise-api

Comment: I've wrote my answer but after all I'll upvote yours Nikos as it's best solution to the problem

Comment: Thanks - Reading the link provided is it correct for me to say that I could use .finally if I don't want IE8 compatibility?

Comment: Currently, Angular dev docs state: *"AngularJS 1.3 is dropping support for IE8[...]AngularJS 1.2 will continue to support IE8, but the core team does not plan to spend time addressing issues specific to IE8 or earlier."* ([ref](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie)). `promise.finally()` is a 1.2 feature, so IE8 is supported in a way.